# Почему не работает шаблон?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Мне нужно написать шаблон, который меняет местами диагонали матрицы. При компиляции выдает ошибку и не знаю как исправить. Подскажите.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
template <typename T>
T diagonal(T **array, int size) {
    T buf;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
              buf=array[i][i];
              array[i][i]=array[i][(size-1)-i];
              array[i][(size-1)-i]=buf;
      }
      return buf;
}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    int size=3;
    int m[size][size];

      for(int i=0;i<size;++i){

            for(int j=0;j<size;++j){
                    cout << "ВВод " << i <<" " << j << ":";
                  cin>>m[i][j];
              }
}
     diagonal(m,size);

      for(int i=0;i<size;++i){
             for(int j=0;j<size;++j)
                    cout<<m[i][j]<<' ';
             cout<<endl;
      }
      system("pause");
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: И что же написано в ошибке? (добавьте в сам вопрос)

Comment: @VTT Серьезность 
Ошибка C2672 "Dia": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция 
Ошибка C2784 T Dia(const T **,int): не удалось вывести аргумент шаблон для "const T **" из "int [3][3]"

Answer (score 3):

Основная ошибка не имеет отношения к шаблонам вообще. Вы, очевидно, полагаете, что к массиву вида `T a[m][n]` можно доступаться через "двойной указатель" `T **p`. Это не так. Эти типы никак не связаны вообще. Встроенный двухмерный массив в С/С++ никак не совместим с "двойным указателем".

А что желать дальше зависит от ваших намерений. Можно вообще написать просто

```
template <typename T>
void diagonal(T &array, int size) {
    std::decay_t<decltype(array[0][0])> buf;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
              buf=array[i][i];
              array[i][i]=array[i][(size-1)-i];
              array[i][(size-1)-i]=buf;
      }
}
```

или

```
template <typename T>
void diagonal(T &array, int size) 
{
  using std::swap;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    swap(array[i][i], array[i][size - 1 - i]);
}
```

тем самым соблюдя принцип "duck typing" шаблонного программирования: все, что нас интересует, это чтобы аргумент поддерживал lvalue выражения вида `array[i][j]`, а уж какой конкретно тип имеет `array` и как он внутренне устроен нам не интересно.

(Кстати, зачем вы возвращаете последний `buf` из функции мне не совсем ясно.)

Но если вы хотите использовать именно `T **`, то от встроенного массива `T a[m][n]` в качестве аргумента придется отказаться. Придется строить вручную jagged array, т.е. массив указателей на массивы.

Это во-первых. Во-вторых, в С++ нет и никогда не было такого

```
int size=3;
int m[size][size];
```

Размер массива в С++ обязан быть константой времени компиляции. Даже если ваш компилятор поддерживает подобные расширенные объявления, мой вариант выше но позволить использовать такой нестандартный тип массива в качестве параметра шаблона.

Answer (score 1):

`T**` реализуется как массив указателей на одномерные массивы, а `T[][]` как массив длиной `size*size`, отсюда два варианта на скорую руку

1. Изменить `m` на динамический массив

   ```
   int **m = new int*[size];
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) m[i] = new int[size];
   ```
2. Поправить шаблон и вызов

   ```
   template <typename T, int size> void diagonal(T array[size][size]) {...}
   diagonal<int, size>(m);
   ```

Может есть варианты по красивее, но на ночь не вспомнил.

3. Можно сделать `template <typename T> void diagonal(T *array, int size) {` и работать с адресацией типа `i*size+j`

Answer (score 0):

Для начала следует избавится от массивов в стиле С. Вместо них следует использовать [`::std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Тогда функцию можно записать вот так (тип и размер выводятся):

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, ::std::size_t size> void // ничего не возвращаем
diagonal(::std::array<::std::array<T, size>, size> & mat)
...
constexpr const ::std::size_t size{3}; // размер массива должен быть константой времени компиляции в любом случае
::std::array<::std::array<int, size>, size> m;
```

Если же хочется непременно с обычными массивами, то можно модифицировать так:

```
template<typename T, ::std::size_t size> void
diagonal(T ( & mat )[size][size])
```

Comment: ::вырви::глазно::всё::таки. `using` тут, наверное, ни к чему.

Comment: @alexolut `using` тут действительно ни к чему (остался от копипасты кода из вопроса), а вот по поводу ::сложных::имен это вообще-то не ко мне вопрос.

Comment: @alexolut, Вы ещё скажите как не использовать namespace в коде тем у кого в проектах по десять реализаций map/vector/list/set и ещё  столько же других одноимённых классов с разным функционалом. Заодно покритекуйте MS за сорсы c# и Sun за сорсы java. Ах да, как там дела обстоят в сорсах stl плюсов? Наверное, и тут MS не хорошо поступили...

Comment: @test123 мне кажется, Вам стоит задать [отдельный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), так как затрагиваемая Вами тема довольно обширна.